# Batch file to search files in a folder

Tags: excel, batch-file, batch-processing

I need a bat file to search excel files in a folder. It should do the following

1. search in a folder
2. looks for excel files after created date
3. if it is older than system date deletes the excel file
4. if not  it runs a converter.js

Can any one help.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Where does created date come from?

Comment: what do you mean with `system date`?

Comment: i want to make a search in a file. i wiil searc excell files . if i find  i will look the date of creation of this file and if it is not equal the SYSDate i will erase else i want to call a js file to convert this excell file

Comment: Ok, as I understand it, you want to search for excel file(s) and check the creation date of the file(s). If the creation date isn't today, you want to delete the file(s), if it is today you want to keep the file(s) and run some jscript code to convert on it/them. Is this correct?

Comment: yes right! @MattWilliamson

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Remove the echo's from the script once you see good output on the screen. Also, I'm not sure how you are running `converter.js` so you'll need to change that line to however you do it and if your file dates are in a different format, you'll have to re-arrange the `"%MM%/%DD%/%YYYY%"` too.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

pushd "C:\location\of\files\"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /o-d /b /tc *.xls') do (
  for /f "tokens=1" %%b in ("%%~ta") do (
    if "%%b" NEQ "%MM%/%DD%/%YYYY%" (
      echo del "%%a"
    ) ELSE (
      echo run converter.js
    )
  )
)
popd
```